# Unable to launch Eclipse RCP application product - The Launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am using Eclipse Juno Service Release 2.
I created a product for existing eclipse RCP application. 
When I click on Launch an Eclipse application in the Overview tab of the .product file, it launches fine. However when I click on the launcher(.exe) in the exported eclipse RCP Product. I get a message - **The TESTLauncher was unable to locate is companion shared library.**

I am using JRE-32 bit and Eclipse Juno 64 bit.

May I know what is causing this issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: Juno is very old. You should move to newer version (Neon) to increase you chance of getting support.

Comment: I agree. But the eclipse RCP application has been built out of Juno libraries. I wanted to know if anything in particular is missed in the .product configuration file which is causing the launch to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the issue.
 This was because of mismatch in JRE and Eclipse versions.
 I was using Eclipse Juno 64 bit with JRE 1.6 32 bit.
 Then I used Eclipse Juno 32 bit with JRE 1.6 32 bit to export my product and was then able to launch the product successfully.
 I read somewhere the SWT libraries of Eclipse are platform dependent. So you won't be able to run, say the 64bit version on a 32bit JRE system.